# Inside my Google Document, can I put a link to a chapter of a second document?

Tags: google-docs

I can create an internal link (within the same document) easily and just reference previously defined Headings.

Can I do the same cross-document?

This means: can I create a link to another document's Heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is advice at [Digital Inspiration](https://www.labnol.org/internet/links-in-google-docs/28010/) from Amit Agarwal (May 28, 2013):

> It is easy to create links that point to any specific paragraph in a long Google Document. Just scroll to that paragraph and put your cursor in the beginning of that paragraph. Now select the Bookmark option from the Insert menu. Google will add a little ribbon to that paragraph – click the ribbon and then click “Link.”
>
> The full hyperlink to that paragraph can now be copied from your browser’s address bar and it will look something like this:
>
> `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1234/<strong>#heading=h.1icy486iph1x</strong>`

Comment: completely forgot about this question. Found that out myself long ago :). Anyhow, thanks! Maybe someone will need it.